# How to render a JSON file using C# MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to render a JSON file in C# using MVC.

I wrote

**In Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<string> Title = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        var json = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
        Rootobject RO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

        Title = RO.items.Select(x => x.title).ToList();
    }

    return View(Title);
}
```

**In Model**

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Item[] items { get; set; }
    public bool has_more { get; set; }
    public int quota_max { get; set; }
    public int quota_remaining { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
    public Owner owner { get; set; }
    public bool is_answered { get; set; }
    public int view_count { get; set; }
    public int answer_count { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public int last_activity_date { get; set; }
    public int creation_date { get; set; }
    public int question_id { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int last_edit_date { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public int reputation { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string user_type { get; set; }
    public int accept_rate { get; set; }
    public string profile_image { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
}
```

**In View**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.Item>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@foreach (var d in Model)
{
    <li>@d.title</li>
}
```

I got an error once I open the web page. I need to list all title of a JSON file, but I cannot get the list. So all I need is to render the data in an html file

Comment: You're returing a List<string> from your ActionResult, therefor, you would iterate that and just use var d in your li elements as it is already the value of title. Also what @Nkosi said.

Comment: You declare the model as `IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.Item>` in the view yet you return a string from the controller. 
This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nkosi I need to do a list of titles

Comment: Update model in view to `IEnumerable<string>` and update loop as well. Do you need anything other than title from list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the model as `IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.Item>` in the view yet you return a list of strings from the controller.

Update model in view to `IEnumerable<string>` and update loop as well.

In View

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@foreach (var title in Model) {
    <li>@title</li>
}
```

If you want to return more details then return the desired information from the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var items = new List<ProjectName.Models.Item>();

    using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(path)) {
        var json = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
        Rootobject RO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

        items = RO.items.ToList();
    }

    return View(items);
}
```

and update the view accordingly

For example.

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.Item>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>
    <h4>@item.title</h4>
    @foreach (var tag in item.tags) {
        <p>@tag</p>
    }
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok .. but what should I do if I need to include more information in the view such as the tags ....

Comment: it's perfect but I think you have to write @tag not tag ... am I wrong?

Comment: @HTMLMan Yeah that was a typo on my part.